# site - is currently unable to handle this request Http error Magento 1.9

Tags: http-error-500, http-request

This page isn’t working www.abc.com.au is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500. In this site we use Magento 1.9

Comment: try uncommenting ini_set('display_errors', 1); from index.php, you may find the error if any and try to solve

Comment: yes I comment but show this error, - Fatal error: Cannot access property Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::$_config in public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 219